# Partial derivative variable in square

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives, partial-derivative

Suppose that you are trying to find the derivative of a function with respect to x^2, ∂f/∂x^2. But the given function is a linear function such that f=3x+5. In the book, it is written that the solution is hidden behind the formula "(1/2x)*(∂f/∂fx)", i.e. 3/2x. How to do it? Is there any rule to apply this simplification?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Let $y = x^2$ so $\frac{\partial y}{\partial x} = 2x$ and find
$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}
  = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} \frac{\partial x}{\partial y}
  = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} \frac{1}{\partial y/\partial x}
  = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} \frac{1}{2x}
$$